# Object transparency is changing the color to black

Tags: excel, vba

I need to place scattered markers on an Excel chart. Each marker should have a certain color and `0.5` transparency.

I have succeeded  to set the color like this:

```
Dim marker As Object
Set marker = ChartObjects("myMap").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i - 1)
    
With marker
    .MarkerStyle = 8
    .MarkerSize = 30
    .Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
End With
```

But when I want to set the the transparency

```
Dim marker As Object
Set marker = ChartObjects("myMap").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i - 1)
    
With marker
    .MarkerStyle = 8
    .MarkerSize = 30
    .Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
    .Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
End With
```

it turns color to transparent black

I have tried to set transparency for the entire graph and is the same problem

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want the forecolor and not the backcolor? `.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)`

Comment: I saw you deleted your comment. I thought it was solved?